# Mvn install falla al compilar en una rama, y funciona en otra que es igual (problema UTF-8)

Tags: java, git, maven

El caso es que estoy en un proyecto bastante grande y tengo un problema al compilar en una determinada rama. Cuando hago `mvn install` me da error en un montón de archivos como que no reconoce caracteres especiales. Al revisarlo son las palabras que llevan acento que hay en las alertas que saltan en determinados casos.

Lo extraño es que para hacer un desarrollo me saqué hace días una rama de esta misma rama en la que tengo el fallo, y a día de hoy me compila bien desde mi rama, pero no desde la rama original.

Compruebo el código de ambas y en los dos casos tienen esas palabras con acentos, pero en una rama falla y en la otra no.

En ambas ramas los ficheros `pom.xml` de maven son los mismos, y en ambos casos se hace referencia a que se use codificación UTF-8.

¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Gracias!

Comment: Los ficheros .xml son archivos planos. Y los editores pueden guardarlos con o sin BOM. Y, suele ocurrir que cuando son guardados con BOM (así lo hace windows por defecto) algunos servidores particularmente en Linux fallen al leerlos. Revisa el archivo problema (copia todo y pega en doc nuevo) y guarda sin BOM usa un editor como notepad++ en win o un ide cualquiera en linux. 
Eso posiblemente resuelva el problema.

Comment: @quevedo Hola! Los ficheros que dan problema son con extensión .java. En principio no parecen ser los XML. Haré lo que me dices con los . java a ver si funciona. Puede ser problema del editor? Uso sublime text

Comment: Los .java también son planos. Mira la configuración del editor (preferencias) y revisa las opciones de guardado. Si usas NetBeans IDE (es el que yo uso) puedes establecer la preferencia para los archivos de código.